# Normal Distribution: Which side of the mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, word-problem

A random variable $X$ represents the number of hours of use until an electronic component needs to be replaced. $X$ is normally distributed with a mean of $27500$ hours and a standard deviation of $4000$ hours. $99$% of the components do not need to be replaced until they have been used for $k$ hours. Find the value of $k$.

The answer in the mark scheme is $36000$. How come? Shouldn't $k$ be below the mean as there is $99$% of devices that still work? I calculated it from the other side of the mean, as I think I need a small number of hours so that $99$% still work. My answer was approximately $18000$.

Comment: Please show your work so others can figure out what you did wrong and provide better feedback

Comment: This is more a matter of language.  The statement is not particularly clear.  I can see an argument in either direction.  The punchline is that 99% of these components will have broken by the 36000 hour mark and only 1% of the components will still be working for longer than 36000 hours.  On the other hand 1% of components will have broken by the 18000 hour mark and 99% of components will work for longer than 18000 hours.  So long as you can understand and appreciate both of those statements, then you are fine.

Comment: @JMoravitz The problem is that this question's mark scheme was made by Cambridge, and it is a past paper for our school. Many solved it correctly except me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the $k$ you are after is referring to the $99$th percentile, as depicted below, which is clearly above the mean $0$, and the shaded area refers to the $36000$ hours your classmates got.

A better reading is thus that
*the last of $99\%$ of the components does not need to be replaced until it has been used for $k$ hours. So after $k$ hours, only $1\%$ of all initial devices are still working.*

[image]

Comment: Hey @Piita, thanks for your answer. k is the number of hours, not the number of devices. Shouldn't that mean that the number of hours should be low so the number of devices still working is high?

Comment: We don't want the 1% of devices that are still running. We want the 99% of devices that are still running. @Piita

Comment: You're amazing! Nobody was able to explain this to me like you. Thank you so much!